# How am I supposed to get past Dogamy and Dogaressa without killing them?

Tags: undertale

How am I supposed to get past Dogamy and Dogaressa without killing them? For reference this is a picture of them:[image: Picture]
but I've tried every act action(And mercy) possible and I still can't get past them! Someone please help. Also I've searched google and the Arqade part of SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like many UNDERTALE boss fights, there is a specific order that must be done in order to pass it. This one works like this.

**Roll in the dirt/mud** which will make them think you are a weird puppy, then
**Sniff** to let them smell you, and then
**Pet**. Make sure you pet both of them, and then you will be able to spare them.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I'm trying to beat the game without killing anyone.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct so that anyone else with the same problem can find it quicker.

Comment: Is... this type of answer to boss fights part of the theme of this game?  This is... a REALLY bizarre answer.

Comment: Note: Your default weapon in the game is a stick. If you equip another weapon, the stick will be in your inventory. If you use the stick in any fights with any dogs, including Dogamy and Dogaressa, you will be able to mercy them right away.

Comment: @Nelson A really bizarre game deserves really bizarre answers. You should totally play it. =)

Comment: There is a hint about this in the His and Her doghouses shortly before you fight these two.  With an easter egg regarding red/green colorblindness...

Answer (score 6):

Another method to spare them is to use the Stick. It's your starting weapon but becomes an inventory item if you replace it (with the Tough Glove or Toy Knife for example).

Use the stick and you will play fetch with the Dogi. This will allow you to spare them quicker and more easily, but doesn't get you their yellow text in the end credits.

This method works on all the dog bosses (Doggo, Lesser Dog, Greater Dog, Dogeressa and Dogamy).